# Knockout get selected value from select from multidimensional array

Tags: knockout.js

I have an object containing several products with variants that the user could select.
I'd like to trigger an event that sends the selected item (or option value) to be able to calculate the total sum.

I've tried back and forward and this is the furthest I've come:

```
<div class="row" data-bind="foreach: {data: additionalProducts, as: 'product'}">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <h4 data-bind="text: product.Name"></h4>
        <p data-bind="text: product.Description"></p>

        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control input-block-level"
                    data-bind="options: product.Variants,
                optionsValue: 'Id',
                optionsText: function(item) {
                   return item.Name + ' - ' + item.Price + ' kr'
                },
                value: $parent.selectedProduct,
                optionsCaption: '-- Välj önskat belopp nedan --'"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

self.selectedProduct = ko.observable();
    self.selectedProduct.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        console.log(newValue);
    });
```

What happens now is that the console first outputs the Id of the selected option, then outputs undefined and resets the two select elements.

The additionalproduct data looks like this:

```
[{"Id":1,"Name":"Finisher t-shirt","Description":"Köp minne från loppet. Snygg specialdesignad t-shirt i funktionsmaterial. Hämtas ut i samband med nummerlappsutdelningen.","Variants":[{"Id":0,"Name":"Ingen t-shirt","Price":0.0},{"Id":1,"Name":"Storlek XS","Price":100.0},{"Id":2,"Name":"Storlek S","Price":100.0},{"Id":3,"Name":"Storlek M","Price":100.0},{"Id":4,"Name":"Storlek L","Price":100.0},{"Id":5,"Name":"Storlek XL","Price":150.0}]},{"Id":2,"Name":"Donation till Amzungo","Description":"Donera gärna en slant till välgörenhet.","Variants":[{"Id":9,"Name":"Jag vill inte donera","Price":0.0},{"Id":10,"Name":"Jag vill donera","Price":25.0},{"Id":11,"Name":"Jag vill donera","Price":50.0},{"Id":15,"Name":"Jag vill donera","Price":75.0},{"Id":12,"Name":"Jag vill donera","Price":100.0},{"Id":13,"Name":"Jag vill donera","Price":150.0},{"Id":14,"Name":"Jag vill donera","Price":200.0}]}]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend splitting the task into several independent bits. You have:

- A product variant. It keeps track of its Id, Name, Price and calculated value for the DisplayText.

  ```
  function Variant(data) {
      ko.utils.extend(this, data);
      this.DisplayText = this.Name + ' - ' + this.Price + ' kr';
  }
  ```
- A product. It keeps track of its Id, Name, Description and Variants, as well as the SelectedVariant.

  ```
  function Product(data) {
      ko.utils.extend(this, data);
      this.Variants = ko.utils.arrayMap(data.Variants, function (v) {
          return new Variant(v);
      });
      this.SelectedVariant = ko.observable();
  }
  ```
- A product selector. It keeps track of all the Products and calculates the Total:

  ```
  function ProductSelector(data) {
      var self = this;
      self.Products = ko.utils.arrayMap(data, function (p) {
          return new Product(p);
      });
      self.Total = ko.computed(function () {
          var total = 0;
          ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.Products, function (p) {
              var selectedVariant = p.SelectedVariant();
              total += selectedVariant ? selectedVariant.Price : 0;
          });
          return total;
      });
  }
  ```

Now you can bind a view to this:

```html
<div class="row" data-bind="foreach: Products">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <h4 data-bind="text: Name"></h4>
        <p data-bind="text: Description"></p>
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control input-block-level" data-bind="
                optionsCaption: '-- Välj önskat belopp nedan --',
                options: Variants,
                optionsText: 'DisplayText',
                value: SelectedVariant
            "></select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<p><b>Total:</b> <span data-bind="text: Total"></span> kr</p>
```

Note that you don't need the `optionsValue` binding if you want knockout to store the selected object *itself* (as opposed to one of its property values).

I've used `ko.utils.extend(this, data);` to initialize objects with the data you pass in. This is convenient and good enough for simple use cases like this one. For more complex cases, have a look at the official [mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) or the [Knockout Viewmodel Plugin](http://coderenaissance.github.io/knockout.viewmodel/).

With these bits in place you can handle your input easily. Expand and run the snippet below to see it work.

```js
function Variant(data) {
    ko.utils.extend(this, data);
    this.DisplayText = this.Name + ' - ' + this.Price + ' kr';
}

function Product(data) {
    ko.utils.extend(this, data);
    this.Variants = ko.utils.arrayMap(data.Variants, function (v) {
        return new Variant(v);
    });
    this.SelectedVariant = ko.observable();
}

function ProductSelector(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.Products = ko.utils.arrayMap(data, function (p) {
        return new Product(p);
    });
    self.Total = ko.computed(function () {
        var total = 0;
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.Products, function (p) {
            var selectedVariant = p.SelectedVariant();
            total += selectedVariant ? selectedVariant.Price : 0;
        });
        return total;
    });
}

var vm = new ProductSelector([
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "Name": "Finisher t-shirt",
        "Description": "Köp minne från loppet. Snygg specialdesignad t-shirt i funktionsmaterial. Hämtas ut i samband med nummerlappsutdelningen.",
        "Variants": [
            {
                "Id": 0,
                "Name": "Ingen t-shirt",
                "Price": 0
            },
            {
                "Id": 1,
                "Name": "Storlek XS",
                "Price": 100
            },
            {
                "Id": 2,
                "Name": "Storlek S",
                "Price": 100
            },
            {
                "Id": 3,
                "Name": "Storlek M",
                "Price": 100
            },
            {
                "Id": 4,
                "Name": "Storlek L",
                "Price": 100
            },
            {
                "Id": 5,
                "Name": "Storlek XL",
                "Price": 150
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "Name": "Donation till Amzungo",
        "Description": "Donera gärna en slant till välgörenhet.",
        "Variants": [
            {
                "Id": 9,
                "Name": "Jag vill inte donera",
                "Price": 0
            },
            {
                "Id": 10,
                "Name": "Jag vill donera",
                "Price": 25
            },
            {
                "Id": 11,
                "Name": "Jag vill donera",
                "Price": 50
            },
            {
                "Id": 15,
                "Name": "Jag vill donera",
                "Price": 75
            },
            {
                "Id": 12,
                "Name": "Jag vill donera",
                "Price": 100
            },
            {
                "Id": 13,
                "Name": "Jag vill donera",
                "Price": 150
            },
            {
                "Id": 14,
                "Name": "Jag vill donera",
                "Price": 200
            }
        ]
    }
]);

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div class="row" data-bind="foreach: Products">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <h4 data-bind="text: Name"></h4>
        <p data-bind="text: Description"></p>
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control input-block-level" data-bind="
                optionsCaption: '-- Välj önskat belopp nedan --',
                options: Variants,
                optionsText: 'DisplayText',
                value: SelectedVariant
            "></select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<p><b>Total:</b> <span data-bind="text: Total"></span> kr</p>

<hr>
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre>
```

Comment: Hot damn - Looks freakin' awesome! I'll be sure to try this out.
Thanks!

Comment: @Jonas Good to hear! :)